# Control $\dot x = -x -u$, $u=u(t)$ from $x(0)=1$ to $x(2)$ s.t $J= -2x^2(2) + \int_0^2 x+x^2+3xu+u^2 dt $ is minimized

Tags: optimization, control-theory, optimal-control

> Control $$\dot x = -x -u$$ from $x(0)=1$ to $x(2)$ such that $$J= -2x^2(2) + \int_0^2 x+x^2+3xu+u^2 \:dt$$ is minimized.

I'm stuck because I don't know what to do about this term, $-2x^2(2)$. How can I apply the Pontryagin Maximum Principle (PMP)? Is there some way I can get this term under the integral? Also, the value of $x(2)$ is unspecified so can I just set $x(2)=a, \: a\in \mathbb{R}$?

**attempt at $-2x^2(2)$ term**

$ \displaystyle -2x^2(2)= -tx^2|_0^2=\int_0^2 (-tx^2)'\: dt = \int_0^2 -x^2-2tx\dot x\: dt$.

Then

\begin{align}
J&= -2x^2(2) + \int_0^2 x+x^2+3xu+u^2 \:dt \\
&=  \int_0^2 -x^2-2tx\dot x\: dt + \int_0^2 x+x^2+3xu+u^2 \:dt \\
&= \int_0^2 -x^2-2tx\dot x + x+x^2+3xu+u^2 \:dt 
\end{align}

Am I on the right track?

Comment: what is PMP ???

Comment: @Ahmad Bazzi Pontryagin Maximum Principle

Comment: It looks like a standard [problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontryagin%27s_maximum_principle#Formal_statement_of_necessary_conditions_for_minimization_problem)

Comment: @d.k.o. so is my approach correct?

Comment: What are you confused about? This is just standard problem with a terminal cost i.e $-2x(2)^2$ term. $$J=S(x(t_f),t_f)+\int_{t_0}^{t_f}L(x(t),u(t),t) \mathrm{d}t$$ now apply PMP, write down Hamiltonian, and follow the steps.